# Can I use a Dictionary to store keywords that I need to loop through a csv file to find?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am writing a python script that will go through a csv file row by row looking for a keyword. Once that keyword is found I need to write that entire row to a new .csv file. I am having trouble writing the for loop to complete this task and I do not understand how to write to a new .csv file. I will post what I have done so far below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# First import csv module to work on .csv file
import csv

#Lets open the files that will be used to read from and write too
infile = open('infile.csv','rb')
outfile = open('outfile.csv','w')


# Lets pass file object through csv reader method
csv_f_reader = csv.reader(infile)
writer = csv.writer(outfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
#Lets create a dictionary to hold all search words as unique keys.
# the associated value will be used to keep count of how many successful
# hits the forloop hits.

search_word={'wifi':0,'WIFI':0,'wi-fi':0,'Wi-Fi':0,'Cisco':0,'cisco':0,'NETGEAR':0,'netgear':0,'Netge$

for csv_line in csv_f_reader:
    match_found = False
    for keyword in search_word.keys():
            for csv_element in csv_line:
                    if keyword in csv_element:
                            match_found = True
                            search_word[keyword] +=1
    if match_found:
            writer.writerow(csv_line)


#Dont forget to close the file
infile.close()
outfile.close()
print search_word.keys(), search_word.values()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a dictionary for what you're describing (unless you're trying to count up the keyword instances). `search_word.keys()` gives you a list anyway which is OK.

First you want to iterate through the csv like this:

```
infile = open('infile.csv')
csv_f_reader = csv.reader(infile)
for csv_line in csv_f_reader:
    print csv_line
```

If you try that, you'll see that each line gives you a list of all the elements. You can use your list of keywords to compare each one and write the ones that pass

```
for csv_line in csv_f_reader:
    for k in search_word.keys():
        if k in csv_line:
             writer.writerow(csv_line)
```

In your case, the keywords aren't exactly the same as the CSV elements, they're inside them. We can deal with this by checking the elements for substrings:

```
for csv_line in csv_f_reader:
    match_found = False
    for k in search_word.keys():
        for csv_element in csv_line:
            if k in csv_element:
                match_found = True
    if match_found:
        writer.writerow(csv_line)
```

One other thing, is you need to open the output file in write mode with:

`outfile = open('outfile.csv', 'w')`

Comment: You can also iterate through the csv with a list comprehension in one line of code, like `rows = [row for row in open('infile.csv')]`

Comment: @Daniel, when possible, it's generally preferred to use a lazy iterator instead of building an unnecessary `list` out of the entire file. Memory requirements are then based on the size of each row (generally small), rather than the size of the entire file.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 interesting; thanks for the tip!  Always good to know the most pythonic solution.

Comment: @ate50eggs If I am using this script on a .csv file with over 70,000 entries. should I redirect the output from the print statement to another file?

Comment: You can skip the first loop. The second code chunk actually does what you're trying to do. I just wanted to show you what the csv parser was doing. If you want to see, dump it to a file or just run it on a small test csv

Comment: @ate50eggs that what I figured. The second for loop does not return anything. the outfile is empty and the script runs for maybe 2 seconds before terminating. I have updated the code block.

Comment: Not that this is the current problem, but use `writer.writerow(line)`. Besides that, your code works for me. Maybe your search terms aren't exactly what's in the file? You might try making a tiny csv for testing. You can make one quickly like this `head -n 3 nvdxmlto2.csv > test.csv`. You could also add in a few of the keywords manually and run it on that to see what's going on.

Comment: @ate50eggs I think maybe it is because the keywords do not show up in a row by themselves but instead they are found in the column of a row in a string (i.e. a summary of an event). Any suggestions for resolving that?

Comment: Yeah, the solution above requires them to be exactly the same. Easy to get around though by adding one more loop. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: @ate50eggs Should I add that forloop or should I replace the current for loop with the new one?

Comment: It's an additional for loop nested in the original one. I edited my answer to add a new code block. Instead of checking the list for an element, it loops through all elements and checks each on for matching substrings.

Comment: @ate50eggs that additional nested for loop did the trick! I will post the updated code for future users. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to use a dictionary for your keywords here. Err... wait, oh you want to keep track of how many times you see each keyword. Your description didn't say that.

Anyway, you should be looping through the lines in the file and the keys. The loop should probably look like this:

```
for line in csv_f_reader:
    for keyword in search_word.keys():
        if keyword in line:
            search_word[keyword] += 1
            writer.write(line)

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

I haven't double checked that you're using the csv module correctly, but that should give you an idea of what it should look like.